# error - tuple index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to define c a class for node that will look like : `3, [5,8,2]`
What i am doing wrong?

```
--------------
# Node Class

class Node():

    def __init__(self,name, neighbors):
        self.name = name
        self.neighbors = []
        self.n_records = 0

    def __str__(self):
        s = "{} (#{}): name: {:3}, neighbors: {}"
        return s.format(self.name,self.neighbors)

    def add_record(self, rec):
        self.records.append(rec)
        self.n_records += 1
```

> ```
> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-18-6d6c9b659eeb> in <module>()
>       4 nodes = Node(1,[5,6])
>       5 
> ----> 6 print(nodes)
>
> <ipython-input-17-f3f5914a055f> in __str__(self)
>      11     def __str__(self):
>      12         s = "{} (#{}): name: {:3}, neighbors: {}"
> ---> 13         return s.format(self.name,self.neighbors)
>      14 
>      15     def add_record(self, rec):
>
> IndexError: tuple index out of range
> ```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve]. It would help, for example, if you fixed your code formatting and provided some code so we can replicate your error.

Comment: Count your `{}`s ? You've got 4 and there's only two possible substitutions...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line

```
s = "{} (#{}): name: {:3}, neighbors: {}"
```

This prepares a string for string formatting. 
Note: Each "{}" without number or identifier in it expects a 
new positional argument that should be passed to `format`. 
In your case, there are 4 such markers, so one expects a call 
of the following format:

```
s.format(argument_brace1, argument_brace2, argument_brace3, argument_brace4)
```

However, your actual call only provides arguments for 2 of these markers:

```
return s.format(self.name, self.neighbors)
```

The additional accesses for the remaining 2 markers raise an `IndexError`.

For more information, consult the [documentation onstring formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).